# Change Length is not showing in Datatable

Tags: datatables

I have configured lengthChange to true still the `length change` is not showing in the table. I tried all the ways still not able to succeed in showing the `length change` .I need help to resolve this issue to display `length change'

```
$('#data-table-new').dataTable({"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    sDom: '<lf<t>ip>',
    "lengthChange": true,
    "aoColumns": [
    { "bSortable": true },
    { "bSortable": true },
    { "bSortable": true },
    { "bSortable": false }
]} );
```